# Docker Login Failed Using mssql-tools

Tags: docker, mssql-tools

SSMS connects just fine. Run this code in PowerShell to duplicate the following error.

Any advice? Thanks!

---

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'SA'..

````
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
#Sql Server cmd Tools
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql-tools

#Set-up the Container:
docker run `
--name MSSQL-Latest `
-p 1433:1433 `
-e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" `
-e "SA_PASSWORD=F00B4rB4z!" `
-v C:\Docker\SQL:/sql `
-d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest


docker exec MSSQL-Latest /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd `
-S localhost `
-U "SA" `
-P "SA_PASSWORD=F00B4rB4z!" ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "SA_PASSWORD=" from the password you are trying to log in. You assigned "F00B4rB4z!" value to `SA_PASSWORD` env, not "SA_PASSWORD=F00B4rB4z!".

If you want to then execute some commands inside your container you could add options: `--tty` to allocate a pseudo-TTY and `--interactive` to keep STDIN open or just use -it for short.

The correct command should be:

```
docker exec -it MSSQL-Latest /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U "SA" -P "F00B4rB4z!"
```

Keep in mind that if you have earlier created any user with SA_PASSWORD, the SA_PASSWORD value being saved on your host disk in the path you specified in the bind mount volume. This bind mount will overrides your SA_PASSWORD in future created containers with the same bind mount volume.

Please, try to avoid using the `latest` tag. This approach may cause inaccuracies because you are not guaranteed which version of docker image you are currently using.